# On existence of right units with control of their norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Does, there exist a Banach algebra with a family of right units with norms converging to 1, but without right unit of norm 1?

Comment: @YemonChoi, $C_0(X)$ is commutative, so right units are just units. But $C_0(X)$ with $X$ non-compact is not unital. So how does $C_0(X)$ answer my question?

Comment: my mistake, I misread your question as asking about right approximate units. I've deleted my previous comment. Sorry.

Comment: @YemonChoi, no problem. Just do me a favour, do not put this question on hold.